# How to run automation test on real smartphone?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, docker, appium

You maybe know selenium which can run some automation on the browser of my desktop.

I would like to run some automation script on a real smartphone.For example if I need to automate some tasks on my instagram app.

I’ve heard about appium and dockers.but i couldn’t find any tutorial which explain me how to do that. Most of the search results are about testing app on some emulator.

Do you know any ressources which can teach me how to automate my smartphone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [Appium](http://appium.io) perspective there is no difference between real device or emulator.

- Android - should work just fine given there is [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) connectivity between the computer where Appium is running and the phone/tablet. All you need to do is to [enable developer mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) and turn on USB debugging
- iOS - a little bit tricky as you need to perform [code signing](https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing/) for WebDriverAgentRunner application. Check out [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/) for detailed instructions. You can also consider using [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) which provides simple GUI wizard allowing setting up Apple Developer account and configure provisioning profiles